# Showing $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(1+i)\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a = (1 + i)\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Show that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/a$ is a field. How many elements does it have?

Revising for exam, this is a question I got confused by. Lost completely as to what the field $\mathbb{Z}[i]/a$ would look like. Could someone explain the steps for solving this problem?

Comment: Hint: $2\in (1+i)\Bbb Z[i]$.

Comment: Hint: in an Euclidean Domain an element is prime iff the quotient is a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID.
- $1 + i$ is irreducible because it has norm $2$, a prime.
- $(1 + i)$ is a maximal ideal.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
{\mathbb Z}[i]/(1 + i) & \cong ({\mathbb Z}[x]/(x^2+1))/(1 + x) \\
%& \cong {\mathbb Z}[x]/(x^2 + 1, 1 + x) \\ 
& \cong ({\mathbb Z}[x]/(1 + x))/(x^2+1) \\
& \cong {\mathbb Z}/(2) \\
& = {\mathbb F}_2.
\end{align*}$$